# Sending a file to a Dynamic port by a TCP Protocol

Tags: c#, sockets, c#-4.0, tcpclient, tcplistener

I am working with an application that receives a file by a TCP protocol, the application processes the file and then sends it by the same protocol, i am receiving the file without problems, my problem is when i try to send the file, because i need to send the file to another application that is listening a Dynamic port, the code that i am using to send these files is:

```
internal void Send(byte[] buffer)
    {
        TcpClient _client = null;
        try
        {
            _client = new TcpClient(RemoteIPaddress, Dynamic_port);

            if (_client != null)
            {
                NetworkStream _clienttStream = _client.GetStream();
                _clienttStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                _clienttStream.Flush();
                _clienttStream.Close();
                _clienttStream = null;
            }
        }
        catch 
        {
            if (_client != null)
            {
                _client.Close();
                _client = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

The question is, how can i send a file by TCP protocol to a remote machine that uses a dynamic port

Answer (score 2):

Typically, the server should listen on a well known port for a connection request.  The response should include the port number that the server will communicate further on.  Then your app connects to that port for transferring the data.

The communication should do the following:

1. Client connects to server on well known port.
2. Server responds with the dynamic port number to use for further communication.
3. Client connects to server on the received port number.
4. Server responds stating connection established.
5. Client transmits data and disconnects.

This is a simplified version of how passive FTP works.

Point is, there are only two ways to connect to a server on a dynamic port.  The first way is outlined above.  If you can't do it that way then your client app will have to do a port scan, sending a connection attempt to every port within a range, and see which one the server responds on.  However, firewalls are generally programmed to notice this type of thing and shut you down (it's hacker behavior).

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how you can determine the dynamic port that the remote machine has selected to use? There is no automated way to do this. The server should either work on a port that both machines are aware of or you should work out a way for them to select a port through some other mode of communication. Either by connecting to a 3rd party server or hosting a web service that the client can access.

Comment: i need to know what Dynamic port is listening from client